# Loading modules with require in Cordova

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I am new to javascript trying out cordova which heavily makes use of the module require(). I went through some tutorials for this like [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) .
I tried out a very simple example from this tutorial and there is something missing it seems.

This is my html code.

```
 <script>
 var abc = require("js/greeting.js");
        function mod() {
            try{
                
                var g =  abc.sayHelloInEnglish();
            console.log("reached the call");
            document.getElementById("modl").innerHTML = g;
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log("error is" + err.message);
            }   
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="mod()">click</button>
```

This is the code for my greeting.js

```
  //var exports = module.exports = {};
     
exports.sayHelloInEnglish = function() {
    return "HELLO";
};

exports.sayHelloInSpanish = function() {
    return "Hola";
};
```

When I click on the button click, it gives an error that abc is not defined. Is there something I am missing here to use the module?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like you're using a node js example (server side) in the browser (client side). If you want to use 'require' in the browser you'll need something like RequireJS. This may be a better place to start: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into that tutorial. You are right. I had mixed up the server side js with the client side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `module.require` is not for browser. You can't use it like you do right inside `script`-tag. The `require` is for node.js (server-side javascript).

If you want to use it inside a browser you should use preprocessing. For example you can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

To learn more - great 3 min video [CommonJS modules](https://egghead.io/lessons/nodejs-what-are-commonjs-modules)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `require`/`module.exports` natively in the browser. It is built into Node.js/io.js and can be run on the server.

If you want to use `require()`/CommonJS modules in the browser, look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

If you want to run Node/io.js code in the browser in general (including but not limited to `require()`/CommonJS), look at [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).

Since you say you are using cordova, my guess is that you don't really need `require()` at all. Just write your HTML/CSS/JavaScript like you would normally and use cordova to package it up. cordova uses `require()` a lot but that should not affect your app's code.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use this npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

> Import files from npm packages into your cordova www/ directory
> automatically, upon cordova prepare, cordova build or cordova run, and
> before anything else is processed.
>
> Oftentimes we want to import the latest files available in npm
> packages into our www/ directory in cordova projects. With this module
> you can do it automatically without building your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use define in require.js is a way of passing a function or the result of. I was struggling with cordova cause one needs to be very carefull the Code needs to be clean. Define will help you if you  only need to put your result as a object or anything inside the defined function and call it at a later time.

```
// obj.js script
define(function(){
{name: "joe",
lastname:"doe"}
})
```

In the other script you only require the file and pass it to a variable. I guess you could even get rid of the inner brackets in obj script.

```
//other.js
var string = require(["obj"])
console.log(string.name) // joe
```